# Displaying values of a table and their foreign keys

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch

I have three tables in my database:

Items 
- itemNumber (PK)
- title
- edition
- subject

Donors
- donorNumber (PK)
- donorName
- donorDepartment

Barcodes
- barcodeNumber (PK)
- dateAdded
- donorNumber (FK)
- itemNumber (FK)

Basically, an item can have many barcodes and there is my problem, I am trying to display the information like this on a table:

Title: Item title
Edition: 2nd Edition
Subject: Computer Programming
Donor Name: John Doe
Donor Department: Technology
Barcodes: 001, Added on: 04/27/18 
          456, Added on: 04/29/18
          734, Added on: 04/29/18
          976, Added on: 04/30/18

However, My code gives me this:

Title: Item title 1
Edition 2nd Edition
Subject: Computer Programming
Donor Name: John Doe
Donor Department: Technology
Barcodes: 001
Added on: 04/27/18

Title: Item title 1
Edition: 2nd Edition
Subject: Computer Programming
Donor Name: John Doe
Donor Department: Technology
Barcodes: 456
Added on: 04/29/18

Title: Item title 1
Edition: 2nd Edition
Subject: Computer Programming
Donor Name: John Doe
Donor Department: Technology
Barcodes: 734
Added on:04/29/18

... and so on.

How can I accomplish my goal? On my second table row I want to display the second item instead of the first item with the second barcode. Here is my code:

```
<?php 

require "dbinfo.php"; 
//connects to database, returns $db  ($db=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password) or die (mysqli_error()); )


$sql="SELECT Items.title, Items.edition, Items.subject, Items.course, Items.image, Barcodes.barcodeNumber, Barcodes.dateAdded, Donors.donorName, Donors.department FROM Barcodes INNER JOIN Items ON Barcodes.itemNumber = Items.itemNumber INNER JOIN Donors ON Barcodes.donorNumber = Donors.donorNumber ORDER BY title ASC";



$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($db));

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  $itemNumber = $row["itemNumber"]; 
  $title = $row["title"];
  $edition = $row["edition"];
  $donorNumber = $row["donorNumber"];
  $donorName = $row["donorName"];
  $barcodeNumber = $row["barcodeNumber"];
  $dateAdded = $row["dateAdded"];


  echo "<table cellpadding = '10'>"; 
  echo"<tr align='left'>";

  echo "<td>$title";
  echo "Edition: $edition";
  echo "Subject: $subject";
  echo "Course: $course";
  echo "Department: $department";
  echo "Donor: $donorName";
  echo "Barcodes: $barcodeNumber ";
  echo "Added on: $dateAdded</td>";     

} 
?> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Of course I am displaying the info on a table, but this is my first time posting here and I do not know how to show my tags.

My first thought was to create a second query to retrieve only the barcodes matching the $itemNumber values retrieved on every row:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT barcodeNumber FROM Barcodes WHERE Barcodes.itemNumber = $itemNumber"; 
result1 = mysqli_query($db, $sql1) or die (mysqli_error($db));
```

and then fetch the barcodes with a while statement

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){ 
     $barcodeNumber = $row["barcodeNumber"];
     echo $barcodeNumber;
     echo"<br />";
}
```

But since it did not work, I gave up trying to fetch the date added values this way.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two ways how to do it.

The first solution is to use ONE query and check inside the `while` loop with an `if` statement when the "item" has been changed from the last iteration. The pseudo code will look like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($row['itemid'] != $lastId) {

        // new item, create new html row
        echo "</tr>\n"; // close the previous one
        echo "<tr>\n"; // start the new one
        echo "    <td>".$row['whatever']."</td>\n";
        echo "    <td>".$row['data']."</td>\n";
        echo "    <td>".$row['you']."</td>\n";
        echo "    <td>".$row['want']."</td>\n";
        echo "    <td>";

        $lastId = $row['itemid'];
    }
    echo "barcode stuff";
}
```

So at the right time, when you get a new item id you cleanup the table/row of the current item and open a new table/row for the new item.

The second solution is to use TWO queries. One query for the item and the other one for the barcodes. So you have one outer while loop for the item and one inner while loop for the barcodes. Pseudo code looks like this:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     // output item data stuff here

     $barcodesResult = SELECT barcode columns FROM barcodes WHERE barcode belongs to item;

     while($barcode = mysqli_fetch_assoc($barcodesResult)) {
         echo $barcode;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it later when I get back home and I will let you know.

Comment: I finally found what my issue was! I was not fetching my $itemNumber variable on my original code! Can't believe it. As soon as I fixed that my inner while run like a charm. However, I had to use your first solution to avoid duplicate values. Thank you very much for your valuable suggestions. I will fix my code in case someone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I inserted a second while loop after `echo Barcodes: $barcodeNumber ";`

`$sql2 = "SELECT barcodeNumber FROM Barcodes WHERE Barcodes.itemNumber = '$itemNumber'";`

`$barcodeResult = mysqli_query($db, $sql2) or die (mysqli_error($db));`

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($barcodeResult)) {

     $barcode = $row["barcodeNumber"];
     echo $barcode;
     echo "<br />";
 }
```

`echo "</td>";`

`$lastItem = $itemNumber; //Thank you Progman!!`
  `}`
  `}`

`echo"</tr>";`

`echo"</table>";`

I placed my condition after the first while and below fetching the itemNumber value like this:

`$itemNumber = $row["itemNumber"];`
  `if ($itemNumber!= $lastItem){`

Thanks so much for your help and I hope this works for other folks who encounter the same problem.